# Deploying a Django application to an offline server

Tags: python, django, deployment

I'm developing a Django application on a CentOS 7 dev machine that has internet access.

Once I have finished it I want to deploy it to a second machine that does not have internet access, also CentOS 7.

If I develop my Django application within a virtual environment, will I be able to just copy the directory over to the offline server?

What difficulties may I encounter?

I may be able to resolve some dependencies on the offline server via a local  yum repo although that's likely to be hit and miss.

Is there anything I can do at the start of this project that will make the deployment easier later on?

Comment: If you could did the deployment on the offline server, that would be great to share your experience, the difficulties encountered and any tips you may have learned.